# Angular Pipe to remove doubles

Tags: angular, pipe

I have drop down menu that lists all the country codes of the customer. At the moment I have the problem that I have a lot of double entries, that is if I have three customers from India my dropdown will show IN, IN , IN instead of just one time. I thought I could fix this with the help of a pipe but am blanking how to implement it.

below is my pipe (which is empty because I can't figure out the code):

```js
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'duplicates'
})
export class DuplicatesPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: any, args?: any): any {
    
    return value;


  }

}
```

and here my html drop down:

```html
  <strong class="ml-2">Country</strong>
     <select class="ml-1" name="countryCode" [(ngModel)]="countryCode" (change)="gender = ''" (change)="activeStatus = ''">
  <option></option>
  <option *ngFor="let customer of customerArray">{{customer.countryCode | duplicates}}</option>
 </select>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you must apply the pipe to the array you are iterating over.

e.g. something like this:

```js
@Pipe({ name: "uniqueCountryCodes" })
export class UniqueCountryCodesPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(customers: Customer[], args?: any): any { 
    return customers.map(c => c.countryCode).filter((code, currentIndex, allCodes) => allCodes.indexOf(code) === currentIndex);
  }

}
```

usage:

```
<option *ngFor="let code of (customerArray | uniqueCountryCodes)">{{ code }}</option>
```

keep im mind that as long the pipe is not [impure](https://angular.io/guide/pipes#pure-and-impure-pipes), it filters only once and won't update the countrycodes when a new customer is added to the customerArray.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need pipe here, you can just remove duplicates from the customerArray itself before binding.

```
let filteredCustomerArray = [];
this.customerArray.filter(cust=>filteredCustomerArray.indexOf(cust.countryCode) === -1 &&
filteredCustomerArray.push(cust.countryCode));
```

now do ngFor over this array.